# Save values in Database with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite

I have a list of markers ( all draggable)  that I load with xml file (generated from a local database with php). 
It is very easy to move the markers, but now I have a little problem to save the new positions in DB(sqlite). I would like to do an update on the database via javascript, but I didn't understand how to do this. I've tried this:

```
function Save()
{

     var db = openDatabase('/var/www/laravel/database/mydb.db', '1.0', 'mydb', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
     for(var i=0;i<marker_list.length;i++)
     {
         var pos= marker_list[i].getPosition();
         var title = marker_list[i].getTitle();
         db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('update marker set position="'+pos+'" where title="'+title+'"');
         });
     }
}
```

and this:

```
function Save()
{

    var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'mydb', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    for(var i=0;i<marker_list.length;i++)
    {
        var pos= marker_list[i].getPosition();
        var title = marker_list[i].getTitle();
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('update marker set position="'+pos+'" where title="'+title+'"');
        });
    }
}
```

But the code doesn't work. 
Can I fix this?
Or should I change the logic ?

Comment: Use `AJAX` to store data

Comment: javascript runs on the browser and there is no connection between the browser and the SQLite database on your server. You have to write a little PHP script that does the database update and sent parameters to that script using AJAX

Comment: where can I find some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Use php ajax call and update the data in the php file that you called in ajax